# Button background color not changing kivy

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Does anyone know why this simple code doesnt work? The button just displays as the default grey

Python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class Main(Widget):
    pass

class X(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    X().run()
```

KV file

```
<Main>:
    Button:
        text: "x"
        background_normal: ""   # I've tried with and without this
        background_color: (1,1,1,1)
```

Comment: Spelling error! Change `backgroud_color` to `background_color`.

Comment: Sorry I spelled it wrong in the post but is well spelled in my code and it still doesn't work, any idea why? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It works, but you need to specify a different color. If `(1,1,1,1)` it just returns the default, but for other combinations the color changes.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder



class Main(Widget):
    pass

sm = Builder.load_string("""

BoxLayout:
    Button:
        background_color: (0,1,1,1)
        
    Button:
        background_color: (1,0,1,1)

    Button:
        background_color: (1,1,0,1)
    
    Button:
        background_color: (1,1,1,1)

    Button:

""")

class X(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    X().run()
```